# Get current textContent from dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div called fnmessages which displays messages sent by users through an input form. I'm trying to get the messages from fnmessages and insert them into a hidden div called hidden_messages.

I've managed to get the current message from fnmessages passed into hidden_messages but the problem is that when another message is added the hidden_messages doesn't update.

http://jsfiddle.net/tj4uk35g/

```
var mockD = document.getElementById("messages").textContent;
$('#hidden_messages').append(mockD);
var storyD = document.getElementById("hidden_messages").textContent;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For what do you need your div to be backed by a hidden element with same content? And how do you intend the hidden field to be updated if the visible one is not even update?

Answer (score 0):

There is no button in your fiddle. You have to add a listener to the click event of the button and then update the divs with the content of the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/zy6k4Lhr/4/

```
document.getElementById("my_button").addEventListener("click", updateHiddenMessages);

function updateHiddenMessages (e) {
    var text = $("#messages").text() + $("#my_input").val();
    $("#messages").text(text);
    $("#hidden_messages").text(text);
    console.log(text);
}
```